Call dlopen by executing shellcode in linux x86_64
I'm trying to play around with asm and shellcode, my target is to manage to dlopen a custom library. I've created a code in C that calls a fake dlopen method, compiled it and used objdump to extract the assembly then write it in a main.S file which later was compiled with nasm.
The idea for the fake dlopen is to take the address of dlopen at runtime and call it without linking to libc. I took a look at an example I've found on github gists, created a placeholder 'DLOPEN__' in my shellcode bytes that will later be replaced with the real dlopen address. I tough I got it right but when I ran my code it crashed with SIGSEGV (Address boundary error).
BITS 64

global _start
section .text

_start:
    call main

main:
    endbr64
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rsp, 16
    mov esi, 2
    lea rax, [rel str_lib]
    mov rdi, rax 
    call dlopen

    mov eax, 60
    xor edi, edi
    syscall

dlopen:
    ret

section .data
str_lib db '/home/nitanmarcel/shell/example/libhello.so', 0

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main() {
char shellcode[] =
    "\xe8\x00\x00\x00\x00"              // 0x0: call 5: calls a subroutine, push eip into the stack (esp)
    "\xf3\x0f\x1e\xfa"                  // 0x5: endbr64 : 
    "\x55"                              // 0x9: push rbp: push word, doubleword or quadword onto the stack
    "\x48\x89\xe5"                      // 0xa: mov rbp, rsp: moves data from src to dst
    "\x48\x83\xec\x10"                  // 0xd: sub rsp, 0x10: substract src and dst, stores result on dst
    "\xbe\x02\x00\x00\x00"              // 0x11: mov esi, 2: moves data from src to dst
    "\x48\x8d\x05\x13\x00\x00\x00"      // 0x16: lea rax, [rip + 0x13]: load effective address
    "\x48\x89\xc7"                      // 0x1d: mov rdi, rax: moves data from src to dst
    "\xe8""DLOPEN__"                    // 0x20: call DLOPEN__: calls a subroutine, push eip into the stack (esp)
    "\xb8\x3c\x00\x00\x00"              // 0x25: mov eax, 0x3c: moves data from src to dst
    "\x31\xff"                          // 0x2a: xor edi, edi: logical exclusive or
    "\x0f\x05"                          // 0x2c: syscall : fast system call
    "\xc3"                              // 0x2e: ret : return from subroutine. pop 4 bytes from esp and jump there.
    "\x00\x2f"                          // 0x2f: add byte ptr [rdi], ch: adds src and dst, stores result on dst
    "\x68\x6f\x6d\x65\x2f"              // 0x31: push 0x2f656d6f: push word, doubleword or quadword onto the stack
    "\x6e"                              // 0x36: outsb dx, byte ptr [rsi]: Output string byte to port
    "\x69\x74\x61\x6e\x6d\x61\x72\x63"  // 0x37: imul esi, dword ptr [rcx + riz*2 + 0x6e], 0x6372616d: signed multiply
    "\x65\x6c"                          // 0x3f: insb byte ptr [rdi], dx: input from port to string
    "\x2f"                              // 0x41: .byte 0x2f: raw byte
    "\x73\x68"                          // 0x42: jae 0xac: jump short if above or equal (cf=0)
    "\x65\x6c"                          // 0x44: insb byte ptr [rdi], dx: input from port to string
    "\x6c"                              // 0x46: insb byte ptr [rdi], dx: input from port to string
    "\x2f"                              // 0x47: .byte 0x2f: raw byte
    "\x65\x78\x61"                      // 0x48: js 0xac: jump short if sign (sf=1)
    "\x6d"                              // 0x4b: insd dword ptr [rdi], dx: input from port to string
    "\x70\x6c"                          // 0x4c: jo 0xba: jump short if overflow (of=1)
    "\x65"                              // 0x4e: .byte 0x65: raw byte
    "\x2f"                              // 0x4f: .byte 0x2f: raw byte
    "\x6c"                              // 0x50: insb byte ptr [rdi], dx: input from port to string
    "\x69\x62\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f"      // 0x51: imul esp, dword ptr [rdx + 0x68], 0x6f6c6c65: signed multiply
    "\x2e\x73\x6f"                      // 0x58: jae 0xca: jump short if above or equal (cf=0)
    "\x00"                              // 0x5b: .byte 0x00: raw byte
;

    // gist.github.com/knightsc/45edfc4903a9d2fa9f5905f60b02ce5a
    int i = 0;
    char *possiblePatchLocation = (shellcode);
    for (i = 0; i < 0x100; i++) {
        possiblePatchLocation++;
        uint64_t addrOfDlopen = (uint64_t)dlopen;
        if (memcmp(possiblePatchLocation, "DLOPEN__", 6) == 0) {
            printf("dlopen @%llx\n", addrOfDlopen);
            memcpy(possiblePatchLocation, &addrOfDlopen, sizeof(uint64_t));
        } 
    }

    void *mem = mmap(NULL, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
                     MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    if (mem == MAP_FAILED) {
        perror("mmap");
        exit(1);
    }

    memcpy(mem, shellcode, sizeof(shellcode));

    if (mprotect(mem, sizeof(shellcode), PROT_READ | PROT_EXEC) == -1) {
        perror("mprotect");
        exit(1);
    }

    void (*func)() = shellcode;
    func();

    munmap(mem, sizeof(shellcode));

    return 0;
}

I have no idea what I did wrong, or even if I did anything right.
I've compiled my code with -zexecstack but that didn't worked either.
As jester mentioned in comments, I've changed my assembly to use mov, rax; call radx, but it still fails with address boundary error. This time I've disabled disabled address randomization and used the dlopen address directly .
.data
lib:
    .ascii "/home/nitanmarcel/shell/example/libhello.so"
.text
.global _start
_start:
    lea rdi, [rip + lib]
    mov rsi, 0x2
    mov rax, 0x7b0a5d8981e0
    call rax


The CALL uses relative encoding but you fill in an absolute address. Also it's just 4 bytes not 8. A simple workaround would be to do mov rax, DLOPEN__; call rax

@Jester I've edited my question to contain the changes you've specified but it still fails with address boundary and I have no idea why

You have retained the exit syscall, right? Also, .ascii does not zero terminate, use .string (or .asciz).

@Jester I did those after, anyway the issue was that since data was before the .text segment it was assembled to code too. Putting it after the text segment it works
